# How do you work in a team with spring roo?

Tags: spring-roo

I'm evaluating Spring-Roo to use in one of my projects but I'm not sure how can it work within a team.

- Everybody in the team can use the roo
  console?
- How do you commit your changes to
  svn?
- How do you manage merges and
  branching?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Brilliant Question - I actually wanted to ask this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here is what I would do:

1. The "Architect Think Tank" in the team can create the basic bootstrap application once they have very hign level domain model carved out.
2. This can then go into SVN.
3. Followed by this team members can fire roo console either from command prompt or STS and start making changes to their respective modules!
4. This then is managed like any other project i.e. team members who create new entities, fields check their changes into svn.

I don't quite see the need for branches. Merging is required even for normal development with multiple team members so I don't see why would it be difficult with Roo.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense... That's the way I would do it as well. The thing is that I'm just starting with Roo and STS and the "10 minutes app" is becoming a "10 hours app"... I had a lot of problems with dependencies and maven because I'm behind a proxy and I'm afraid of how is it going to work within a team (I imagine all sort of problems just to have the local environment running on each team member). I guess I just have to try it...

Comment: If you are behind the proxies - you could configure your settings.xml of maven to take care of that. If this file is shared across the team members then they could use roo as well. The other thing to remember is setting up maven repo is going to be one time job and wouldn't be a hassel everytime. One final thing, I also had real trouble trying the Roo first time. And I found this article (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-springroo1/?ca=drs-) better than what Spring Source had to offer.

Comment: Thanks! that's a great article.

Answer (score 2):

From Ben Alex in the [Spring Roo forum](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=67):

> In general I wouldn't recommend
>   checking the ITDs into source control
>   given Roo can rebuild them (a bit like
>   your javac compiler builds .class
>   files so you don't check those in).
>
> Git is an exception to this general
>   advice though, because Roo has
>   addon-git which offers a very good
>   automatic integration at a commit
>   tracking level with what Roo's doing
>   (including the ITDs).

One thing to note is that there is no official support for SVN that I've seen, only an addon for git. Another user suggested using Maven's support for Subversion.

Your build/deploy procedures will also be a factor.